# Email::Valid trouble with utf8

Tags: perl

I need to validate some e-mail addresses that have in the From: field unicode characters like:

```
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Jos=E9_name?= <J.name@domain.tld>
```

This value gets saved in the $from variable.

With this code

```
my $validator = Email::Valid->new();
my $addr = $validator->address( $from );
print $addr, "\n";
```

I am getting Use of uninitialized value $addr in

The same code works fine with values not containing unicode characters. I have tried using binmode (STDIN, ':utf8'); but that does not solve it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Jos=E9_name?= <J.name@domain.tld>` is not an email address. It's a MIME header. The value of the MIME header is `José name <J.name@domain.tld>`

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the [cross post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1092570):

> The problem is that the from address is an email header part. And in a header only ASCII is valid. That's the reason why only ASCII encoded strings can be valid. Therefore the word containing the non-ascii character `é` is encoded as `=?iso-8859-1?Q?Jos=E9_Name?=`.
>
> When you take this byte string into the validation routine everything is fine. So, IMHO, the solution must be that you encode the unicode string representing the email address in a valid ascii representation.
>
> ```
>   #!/bin/perl
>   use strict;
>   use warnings;
>   use 5.010;
>
>   use Email::Valid;
>   use Data::Dumper;
>   use Encode qw(encode decode);
>
>   my $utf8_from = decode('UTF-8', 'José <J.name@web.de>');
>   my $from = encode('MIME-Header', $utf8_from);
>   say "Mail: $from";
>   my $validator = Email::Valid->new();
>   if(my $addr = $validator->address( $from )) {
>       say "OK: ", Dumper($addr);
>   }
>   else {
>       say "Not valid";
>   }
> ```
>
> Outputs:
>
> ```
>   Mail: =?UTF-8?B?Sm9zw6kg?=<J.name@web.de>
>   OK: $VAR1 = 'J.name@web.de';
> ```